Godot 4 Scene Switching causes no scene when using arguments, displays scene when using void
Im implementing a simple scene switcher while learning to program a game. I followed this youtube tutorial and looked to implement it myself.
First was the creation of a global scene switcher, here is mine:
extends Node

var current_scene = null

func _ready() -> void:
    var root = get_tree().root
    current_scene = root.get_child(root.get_child_count() - 1)

func switch_scene(res_path):
    call_deferred("_deferred_switch_scene", res_path)

func _deferred_switch_scene(res_path):
    current_scene.free()
    var s = load(res_path)
    current_scene = s.instantiate()
    get_tree().root.add_child(current_scene)
    get_tree().current_scene = current_scene

Then I implemented a signal in the main town here:
extends Node2D

func _on_house_one_door_body_entered(body):
    SceneSwitcher.switch_scene("res://scenes/house_one.tscn")

When I use the code as is, it results in a grey screen. When I replace "body" with "() -> void:", the main town works, but the function doesnt work. However I do recieve this error in the debugger when I walk into the door:

emit_signalp: Error calling from signal 'body_entered' to callable: 'Node2D(pallet town.gd)::_on_house_one_door_body_entered': Method expected 0 arguments, but called with 1.

So I believe it is recognizing the collision.
The player has a characterbody2d and a collisionshape2d, and the door has an area2d and a collisionshape2d with monitoring enabled.

In fact, you have completely disabled the _on_house_one_door_body_entered signal, it is obliged to receive a collision object, but you have removed it and it is no longer called.
Why you get a gray screen is a screen without scenes, in fact, the old scene was deleted, but the new one has not yet been created OR it was created in an invisible position. Then it should also be moved to (0, 0) or to the center, depending on your centering.
The code itself for getting a new scene does not look suspicious, I do the same in my projects and it works.

So it is deleting the old scene, and moving on to the new scene? This is odd because this is when I launch the program, not when I interact with the door.
